# Linking a PictureBox to a object from a class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am making a game in a Windows Form Application. I currently have a sprite that I can successfully move around the screen by using the arrow keys. I would like be able to add more sprites later on that can also move around the screen with the arrow keys. 
I currently have a Player class that has all the attributes for the object "H". The PictureBox I currently have moving around is named placeholder1. I would like to be able to assign a Player object to a PictureBox, if that's possible, or something similar to that.

```
public class Player
{
    // class members 

    public string name;
    public int HP;
    public int currentHP;
    public int attack;
    public int defense;
    public int critical;

    public void Character(string name, int HP, int currentHP, int attack, int defense, int critical)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.HP = HP;
        this.currentHP = currentHP;
        this.attack = attack;
        this.defense = defense;
        this.critical = critical;
    }

}
```

This is my current Player class

```
public partial class Gameplay : Form
{
    public void Player()
    {       
        Player[] H = new Player[1];

        H[0] = new Player();
        H[1] = new Player();

        H[0].Character("Faye", 24, 24, 8, 5, 2);
        H[1].Character("Robin", 20, 20, 7, 6, 4);
    }

    public Gameplay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Gameplay_KeyDown);
    }

    public int movesLeft = 6;

    // movement of character
    public void Gameplay_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (movesLeft > 0)
        {
            int x = placeholder1.Location.X;
            int y = placeholder1.Location.Y;


            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) x += 64;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) x -= 64;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) y += 64;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) y -= 64;

            placeholder1.Location = new Point(x, y);

            movesLeft--;
        }

        // Temporary developer option to skip to end screen
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            EndGame endGame = new EndGame();
            endGame.Show();
            endGame.Location = Location;
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code that I currently have in the form that I have the gameplay in. I have created an array for the Player characters, and the code that I have made for moving the current, singular PictureBox.

Comment: You can use the Tag property. It will accepty any object including coltrols or List<control> etc.. -  but you must cast it to what ever you put there. If you plan for growth maybe create a class to hold various things and put ot there..

Comment: I don't understand that 'Linking a PictureBox to a object from a class'. Can you describe it in detail? Or what is your expected result?

Comment: I have a picture box which is my sprite. I have a Player class which contains all the attributes for the human players. I have code that can move the picture box, but I have to specify which picture box exactly it's supposed to move. I want to be able to have the player stats appear somewhere when a particular picture box sprite is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I would spawn it using graphic.draw and draw the image directly onto the form and then move it this way instead of linking it to the picture box

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new form to show the Player characters.

I make a code example, which may meet your requirements.

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public PictureBox Pic
        {
            get
            {
                return pictureBox1;
            }
            set
            {
                pictureBox1 = value;
            }

        }


        public int movesLeft = 10;
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyCode==Keys.F1)
            {
                Form2 form = new Form2();
                form.ShowDialog();
            }
            if (movesLeft > 0)
            {
                int x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
                int y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;


                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) x += 64;
                else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) x -= 64;
                else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) y += 64;
                else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) y -= 64;

                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);

                movesLeft--;
            }

        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form = new Form2();
            form.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
    public class Player
    {
        public string name;
        public int HP;
        public int currentHP;
        public int attack;
        public int defense;
        public int critical;

        public void Character(string name, int HP, int currentHP, int attack, int defense, int critical)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.HP = HP;
            this.currentHP = currentHP;
            this.attack = attack;
            this.defense = defense;
            this.critical = critical;
        }

    }
```

Form2:

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        List<Player> list = new List<Player>();
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            comboBox1.Items.Add(@"F:\pic\1.jpg");
            comboBox1.Items.Add(@"F:\pic\2.jpg");
            list.Add(new Player { name = "1.jpg", attack = 1, critical = 2, currentHP = 3, defense = 4, HP = 10 });
            list.Add(new Player { name = "2.jpg", attack = 3, critical = 5, currentHP = 7, defense = 2, HP = 10 });
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name = Path.GetFileName(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            Player player = list.Where(p => p.name == name).First();
            txtname.Text = player.name;
            txtattack.Text = player.attack.ToString();
            txtcritical.Text = player.critical.ToString();
            txtcurrenthp.Text = player.currentHP.ToString();
            txtdefense.Text = player.defense.ToString();
            txthp.Text = player.HP.ToString();
            Form1 form1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
            form1.Pic.Image = Image.FromFile(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

        }

        private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
            form1.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Result:
[image]